# Как встроить модуль в проект с++

Tags: c++

Работаю с opencv. Хотелось бы отслеживать результаты вычислений в режиме реального времени на графике. Попробовал cv::plot::Plot2D, но для моих задач оказался не достаточно функциональным. Погулив нашёл проект [CvPlot](https://github.com/Profactor/cv-plot). Я новичок в с++, поэтому не смог интегрировать этот модуль в своей проект. Нужен совет в настройки. Работаю на ubuntu в Сlion

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
set(target project)
project(${target})
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++17")
include_directories(C:\\Users\\...\\cv-plot-1.2.2\\CvPlot\\inc)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS program_options)
find_package(Ceres REQUIRED)
include_directories(${target})
add_executable(${target} ${target}/main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(${target} ${OpenCV_LIBS} ${CERES_LIBRARIES} ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: Там есть инструкция. Что вы попробовали и какие ошибки получили?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, проблема в том, что я не совсем понимаю, как воспользоваться этой инструкцией из-за недостатка опыта. Поправил вопрос, вот так у меня оформлен CmakeList проекта

Comment: Открываю https://github.com/Profactor/cv-plot/blob/master/doc/integration.md , и они там пишут что-то типа 1. Заинклудьте наш хедер. 2. Перед этим сделайте `#define CVPLOT_HEADER_ONLY`. И все.